# change attribute of input checkbox and see changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to select some elements from my table and set attribute 'checked'.

***That's my code:***

```
for (var i=0 ; i<$scope.assets.length ; i++ ){
          if ($scope.assetsFromModel.includes($scope.assets[i].interfaces.ip_addresses[0].value)){
          var el =  angular.element($scope.assets[i].interfaces.ip_addresses[0].value);
          console.log(el.attr('checked','checked'));
          }
}
```

As you can see I get the elements with angular.element (I see in the console that I found the elements I need) but nothing happen.
what should I do?

Comment: Why not use the [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive? Much easier and better to implement the "angular way"

Comment: Or use `ng-model` which takes care of state for you

Comment: but generally, if i want to change attributes and see changes (i.e grayed out - disabled) what i need to do?